# Why is readf not behaving as expected?

Tags: d, dmd

```
import std.stdio;

void main(){

  int n;
  while(readf("%d", &n)){
    if(n == 11)
      break;
    writeln(n);
  }
}
```

The first iteration works, and it prints `n`, but after that `readf()` never returns.

The documentation has only a single line explaining `readf()`:

> **uint readf(A...)(in char[] for­mat, A args);**
>
> ```
>    For­mat­ted read one line from stdin.
> ```

Am I do something wrong? or is there something wrong with `readf()`?  I just need to read numbers from the standard input.

using: DMD 2.054 64-bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's because `readf` handles spaces differently than `scanf` in C. You need to explicitly read in the spaces, so change `readf("%d", &n)` to `readf("%d ", &n)` and it should work (hopefully).

Here's a quote from Andrei, who implemented the function:

> This is by design. The example works when modified as follows:
>
> import std.stdio;
>
> void main() {
>       int i, j;
>       readf("%s", &i);
>       readf(" %s", &j);
>   }
>
> The space before the second parameter tells readf to read and skip all
>   whitespace before attempting conversion.
>
> I've implemented readf to be a fair amount more Nazi about whitespace
>   than scanf in an attempt to improve its precision. Scanf has been
>   famously difficult to use for complex input parsing and validation,
>   and I attribute some of that to its laissez-faire attitude toward
>   whitespace. I'd be glad to relax some of readf's insistence on precise
>   whitespace handling if there's enough evidence that that serves most
>   of our users. I personally believe that the current behavior (strict
>   by default, easy to relax) is best.

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/bugs/Issue_4656_New_stdio.readf_does_not_ignore_white_space_24214.html